# Difference between error reporting and ERRMODE_EXCEPTION

Tags: php, pdo

I really can't understand why we should set at the top of a PHP data Object PDO connection file:

`error_reporting(E_ALL);//When we are in a development process;`

Or

`error_reporting(0);//To shut off all errors when web app is live`

And at the same time when we are creating our connection parameters we should add:

`setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );`

My question is what is the difference and why we use the both of `error_reporting` and `ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` in the same file ? What are the roles of each one of them ? Is their any difference ?

Comment: `error_reporting` is for your PHP errors, while the other is for your PDO class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the initial statement is wrong.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

should be always the same in ALL environments.

While regarding the difference between the two,`error_reporting()` is a **PHP**-wide related setting, responsible for all PHP errors, and

```
setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
```

is for PDO only.

So you can tell why you have to use both: error_reporting(E_ALL) will make you aware of all PHP errors, like missing variable or a filesystem permission problem. While PDO's setAttribute just tells PDO to report its own errors and so make them available through error_reporting(E_ALL).

The proper settings would be:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
```

- in ALL environments.

And then

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

when we are in a development process;

```
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
ini_set('log_errors', 1);
```

To shut off **displaying** all errors when web app is live, while logging them for the developer's reference.

Comment: I liked your phpdelusion site and I will learn from it. Thanks

Comment: what is the log_errors ? Why we should use it with display_errors ?

Comment: Glad it helped. Feel free to ask any questions.

Comment: we should use log_errors on a live site. otherwise we won't be able to see the errors actually - you cannot sit at the every user's screen actually. The only way to see the error is to peek into the log. That is why logging errors is essential on a live site. At the same time display_errors on a live site have to be set to zero, to prevent leaking the errors to the users.

Comment: if i am currently on wampserver how to see the log errors if i want to just make some test with `log_errors` ?

Comment: Well Inever used wamp but I am pretty sure you can google something like where is a php error log file in wamp